# linq EnumerableQuery<Char?>?

Tags: linq

Any idea how to retrieve the value inside EnumerableQuery I wanna retrieve "Y" or Null for create, update, delete column as the same like I did to Read column, but instead of return "Y" or NULL, it return as EnumerableQuery, and I had no idea how to make it

```
from a in MenuFunctions
where a.Scd == 'R' && a.Ise == 'Y'
select new{
    a.Mcd,
    Read = a.Ise,
    Create = (from b in MenuFunctions
                where b.Pcd== a.Mcd && b.Psc == a.Scd && b.Ise=='Y' && b.Scd =='C'
                select b.Ise),
    Update = (from b in MenuFunctions
                where b.Pcd== a.Mcd && b.Psc == a.Scd && b.Ise=='Y' && b.Scd =='U'
                select b.Ise),
    Delete = (from b in MenuFunctions
                where b.Pcd== a.Mcd && b.Psc == a.Scd && b.Ise=='Y' && b.Scd =='D'
                select b.Ise),
}
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Can you please be a little more clear about what it is you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from a in MenuFunctions
where a.Scd == 'R' && a.Ise == 'Y'
select new{
    a.Mcd,
    Read = a.Ise,
    Create = (from b in MenuFunctions
                where b.Pcd== a.Mcd && b.Psc == a.Scd && b.Ise=='Y' && b.Scd =='C'
                select b.Ise).firstOrDefault() == null ? "N" : "Y",
    Update = (from b in MenuFunctions
                where b.Pcd== a.Mcd && b.Psc == a.Scd && b.Ise=='Y' && b.Scd =='U'
                select b.Ise).firstOrDefault() == null ? "N" : "Y",
    Delete = (from b in MenuFunctions
                where b.Pcd== a.Mcd && b.Psc == a.Scd && b.Ise=='Y' && b.Scd =='D'
                select b.Ise).firstOrDefault() == null ? "N" : "Y",
}
```

Ok, I figure it out now, I need to use **firstOrDefault** to return the value from it
and by adding  **== null ? "N" : "Y"**, I also solve the null value inside the column :)
but not sure if any better linq method to perform the same function as this

Comment: Your long sub-selects can be written `MenuFunctions.Any(b => b.Pcd== a.Mcd && b.Psc == a.Scd && b.Ise=='Y' && b.Scd =='C') ? 'Y' : 'N'`.